Calculating the geometric difference between two vector layers
The difference function below, which calculates the boolean difference between two vector layers, relies on two private functions difference_recursive and inner_difference_recursive. How would one remove the code duplication to combine these two functions into a single recursive function?
The differences between difference_recursive and inner_difference_recursive are:

The input_geom argument type is a reference (&Geometry) and owned data (Geometry) respectively.
They may return Some(input_geom.clone) or Some(input_geom) respectively.

I have posted another question where I have tried to distill the problem to the general case.
To explain further, the first time the recursive function is called, the input_geom argument is provided by the FeatureIterator which returns references. Attempting to dereference the reference returned by the FeatureIterator produces the compiler error cannot move out of *input_geom which is behind a shared reference. For subsequent calls to the recursive function, the argument is the result of the difference function which returns owned data.
use gdal::vector::{FeatureIterator, Geometry, LayerAccess};

fn difference_recursive(input_geom: &Geometry, mut features: FeatureIterator) -> Option<Geometry> {
    match features.next() {
        None => Some(input_geom.clone()),
        Some(feature) => match feature.geometry() {
            None => Some(input_geom.clone()),
            Some(overlay_geom) => match input_geom.difference(overlay_geom) {
                None => None,
                Some(output_geom) => inner_difference_recursive(output_geom, features),
            },
        },
    }
}

fn inner_difference_recursive(
    input_geom: Geometry,
    mut features: FeatureIterator,
) -> Option<Geometry> {
    match features.next() {
        None => Some(input_geom),
        Some(feature) => match feature.geometry() {
            None => Some(input_geom),
            Some(overlay_geom) => match input_geom.difference(overlay_geom) {
                None => None,
                Some(output_geom) => inner_difference_recursive(output_geom, features),
            },
        },
    }
}

pub fn difference(
    input: gdal::Dataset,
    overlay: gdal::Dataset,
    output_filename: &str,
) -> Result<(), String> {
    // Setup input layer
    let mut input_layers_iter = input.layers();
    let mut input_layer = match input_layers_iter.next() {
        Some(input_layer) => input_layer,
        None => return Err("No input layer".to_string()),
    };

    // Setup overlay layer
    let mut overlay_layers_iter = overlay.layers();
    let mut overlay_layer = match overlay_layers_iter.next() {
        Some(overlay_layer) => overlay_layer,
        None => return Err("No overlay error".to_string()),
    };

    // Setup output layer
    let driver = input.driver();
    let mut layer_options = gdal::vector::LayerOptions::default();
    let srs = input_layer.spatial_ref();
    layer_options.srs = srs.as_ref();
    let mut output_datasest = match driver.create_vector_only(output_filename) {
        Ok(ds) => ds,
        Err(_) => return Err("Failed to createt output layer dataset".to_string()),
    };
    let mut output_layer = match output_datasest.create_layer(layer_options) {
        Ok(layer) => layer,
        Err(_) => return Err("Failed to create output layer".to_string()),
    };

    // Iterate over input layer features
    for input_feature in input_layer.features() {
        if let Some(input_geom) = input_feature.geometry() {
            if let Some(output_geom) = difference_recursive(input_geom, overlay_layer.features()) {
                let _result = output_layer.create_feature(output_geom);
            }
        }
    }

    // Save data
    if let Err(_) = output_datasest.flush_cache() {
        Err("Error saving data.".to_string())
    } else {
        Ok(())
    }
}




Sorry, but I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. Why do you "need" a reference for the first run and owned date for the remaining? Can't you you dereference needed data? And btw, the returns are superfluous.

The first time the function is called, the input geometry comes from the gdal::vector::FeatureIterator which returns references. Trying to dereference this produces the compiler error "cannot move out of *input_geom which is behind a shared reference".

I've updated the question to hopefully make it clearer.

The solution is to use Cow:
pub fn difference_recursive<'a>(
    input_geom: Cow<'a, Geometry>,
    mut features: FeatureIterator,
) -> Option<Geometry> {
    match features.next() {
        None => Some(input_geom.into_owned()),
        Some(feature) => match feature.geometry() {
            None => Some(input_geom.into_owned()),
            Some(overlay_geom) => match input_geom.difference(overlay_geom) {
                None => None,
                Some(output_geom) => difference_recursive(Cow::Owned(output_geom), features),
            },
        },
    }
}

The original call to the function then wraps the input in a Cow via Cow::Borrowed(input_geom).

Nice job finding a solution. A Cow is a good tool when you don't know if you have a borrowed or an owned reference, but it also seems overly complex when you do know what you have (as we do in this case).

The smallest change: Instead of passing in an owned FeatureIterator, pass in mutably borrowed FeatureIterator: &mut FeatureIterator.
fn difference_recursive(input_geom: &Geometry, features: &mut FeatureIterator) -> Option<Geometry> {      
    match features.next() {      
        None => Some(input_geom.clone()),      
        Some(feature) => match feature.geometry() { : Feature<'_>    
            None => Some(input_geom.clone()),      
            Some(overlay_geom) => match input_geom.difference(overlay_geom) { : &Geometry    
                None => None,      
                Some(output_geom) => difference_recursive(&output_geom, features) : Geometry input_geom:    
            },      
        },      
    }      
}     

Then you can delete inner_difference_recursive.
You'll need to update the call-site to reflect this mutable borrow like this:
     // Iterate over input layer features
     for input_feature in input_layer.features() {
         if let Some(input_geom) = input_feature.geometry() {
-            if let Some(output_geom) = difference_recursive(input_geom, overlay_layer.features()) {
+            let mut overlay_layer_features = overlay_layer.features();
+            if let Some(output_geom) = difference_recursive(input_geom, &mut overlay_layer_features) {
                 let _result = output_layer.create_feature(output_geom);
             }
         }

As an aside, I'd consider making this method not recursive, because for each recursion, you're passing by reference (borrowing the newly constructed geometry), you're keeping each new intermediate output_geom around.
I'd probably do some kind of for loop, like this:
fn difference_iterative(input_geom: &Geometry, features: FeatureIterator) -> Option<Geometry> {    
    let mut output_geom = input_geom.clone(); : Geometry          
    for feature in features { : Feature<'_>                       
        match feature.geometry() {                                
            None => continue,                                     
            Some(overlay_geom) => match output_geom.difference(overlay_geom) { : &Geometry    
                None => return None,    
                Some(next_geom) => output_geom = next_geom : Geometry    
            }    
        }    
    }    
    Some(output_geom)    
}

Note that this version takes an owned FeatureIterator again! So you'd have to revert the call site to look more like your initial one.
Getting comfortable with the difference between owned and borrowed data is essential to becoming proficient with rust. If you have time, have a look at https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-00-understanding-ownership.html

Yes, good spot on the recursive function. I was at a loss for a while trying to figure out why it was crashing on larger data sets with the simple message “KILLED”. Eventually I realised it was the recursion that was the culprit. At least now I know about tail call optimisation and what an OOM killer is.
