Function that accepts either owned data of type T or a ref to data of type T and returns original data or clone of referenced data respectively
How can you write a function that accepts either data of type T or a reference to data of type T, and returns either the original data or a clone of the referenced data respectively? Something like this:
fn foo(input: T or &T) -> T {
    if input is &T {
        input.clone()
    } else {
        input
    }
}


The idiomatic way would be: "take a T and let the caller decide if they want to clone it"

Maybe you want Cow.

fn foo<T: Clone>(input: impl Borrow<T>) -> T { input.borrow().clone() } ?

@cafce25, the caller does not know if they want to clone it, that's the point of the function. See my other question for a concrete example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79036119/writing-a-rust-tool-to-calculate-the-geometric-difference-between-two-vector-lay

@GeographyJames if your function needs an owned value and the caller only has a reference (or want's the value to remain accessible) they have to clone it, otherwise they're good to pass you their value, I don't see how the caller isn't in a better position to determine if a clone is needed and make it explicit there.

The function doesn't know if it needs an owned value until it has evaluated some predicates, it only needs owned data under some circumstances.

You want to pass in something that can be converted into Cow:
use std::borrow::Cow;

fn main() {
    let owned = String::from("Hello world.");
    let _clone = owned.clone();
    let borrowed = &_clone;
    assert_eq!(borrowed_or_owned(owned), "Hello world.".to_string());
    assert_eq!(borrowed_or_owned(borrowed), "Hello world.".to_string());
}

fn borrowed_or_owned<'a, T>(value: impl Into<Cow<'a, T>>) -> <T as ToOwned>::Owned
where
    T: ToOwned + 'a + ?Sized,
{
    value.into().into_owned()
}

Playground

Could you explain, therefore, how one would use this solution for a concrete type? For my specific case, the type is a gdal::vector::Geometry (please see my other question for full example).

Then you really want to read up on Cow (link above)`.

This would also require Geometry and &'a Geometry to implement Into<Cow<'a, Geometry>>: Playground.
If the gdal library does not provide this implementation, you must pass in the Cow manually at the caller's side: Playground

Alternatively you can implement a helper trait for Geometry: Playground

This is perfect, thanks for taking the time to spell it out to me. I was feeling a bit bewildered after looking at the documentation.
